# Which of these values are NOT in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of values, and want to know which ones don't already exist in the table. (This is on sql server 2000)

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable ( foo VARCHAR(10) )
GO

INSERT INTO myTable
        ( foo
        )
        SELECT 'aaa'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'bbb'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'ccc'
GO

SELECT foo
    FROM myTable
    WHERE foo IN ( 'aaa', 'cat', 'bbb', 'dog' ) 
-- returns 'aaa' and 'bbb'
```

I need to write a query that returns 'cat' and 'dog'.

```
SELECT foo
    FROM myTable
    WHERE foo ????? ( 'aaa', 'cat', 'bbb', 'dog' ) 
-- returns 'cat' and 'dog'
```

Is there a simple way to do this in a query?

Due to the way the app interacts with the database, I'd rather not, say, create a temp table

Comment: Is the list of values small? If it is then you could simply fetch the ones that already exist from the database and then do the filtering in the application instead, with no noticeable performance loss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could construct a table with `union all` and join on that, filtering on the rows that are not matched by the join:

```
SELECT     myList.foo
FROM       (
               SELECT 'aaa' as foo
               UNION ALL SELECT 'cat'
               UNION ALL SELECT 'bbb'
               UNION ALL SELECT 'dog'
           ) myList
LEFT JOIN  myTable
ON         myTable.foo = myList.foo
WHERE      myTable.foo is null
```

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS is the thing (NOT EXISTS, in fact)

```
select foo from myTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from myTable where foo in('cat', 'dog'));
```

Not the cleanest way, neither the cleanest. Soehow, it could work.

Comment: If I already know which specific ones to search for... I don't need this query :-)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Fast reading = incomplete stuff 

* alfabravo blushes *